Get a obstacle avoidance path base on a grid-based map and non-grid based movement

black line is grid-based path got from A* algorithm, and red one is smoothed path by use Funnel algorithm.
when B move through T or stop at T, it will overlap with A, My problem is how to get a path that smartly avoid A. and because i need preview the path, so it cant use collision test every frame.
i could scale obstacle radius to make more obstacle cell, but it will make A too far from B in visual, and it will still overlap when B is a bigger unit.
i wonder if there is a better way to resolve this problem.

can you augment your funnel algorithm by allowing it to grow the obstacles it is avoiding by function of the moving object's size?

I believe your options are to "scale the obstacle radius" to take into account the radius of unit B; or build in some logic for B to avoid/walk alongside obstacles when actually moving along the path.

@ratchetfreak i dont know how to, funnel algorithm just do work of simplify the given path, it doesnt know and care how big of object's size or obstacle's

If a unit is larger than the size of your grid, and you try to pathfind using grid centers, you will always have overlap on all adjacent grid spaces. Instead, if a unit is larger than the size of the grid, you can find the smallest square of grid squares that contains it and pathfind in the larger grid.
